# Does this theorem have a formal name?

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for a referable name for this theorem if one exists.

The group $Z_n \times Z_m$ is isomorphic to $Z_{nm}$ if $n, m$ are relatively prime.

Thank you.

Comment: It's Chinese Remainder Theorem, basically. Just restricted to the additive groups.

Answer (score 1):

Its called the Chinese Remainder Theorem. From a quick google, it appears with your formulation [here](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~zeph/4261/lectures/number-theory-2.pdf).

Comment: Link is broken. If someone for some reason wants this, there is a backup on the Internet Archive [here](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~zeph/4261/lectures/number-theory-2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is the Chinese Remainder Theorem.